# Efficient way of choosing lottery ticket numbers

Tags: combinatorics, expected-value, recreational-mathematics, lotteries

You want to buy a given number $n$ of lottery tickets, in each of which you have to guess exactly 6 numbers from 1 to 100. If you get 0 or 1 numbers right, you don't get any money. If you get $i>1$ numbers right, you'll get $x_i$ dollars (i.e. if your guess was 1,2,3,4,5,6 but the numbers were 1,2,3,4,5,7 you'll win $x_5$).

**Is there an optimal strategy for choosing the numbers on the $n$ lottery tickets?**

For $n=2$ (actually this guess generalizes for all $n \leq 16$), my guess is that betting on, say, $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)$ and $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7)$ will result on a lower expected value of money won than, say, $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)$ and $(7,8,9,10,11,12)$ because the values "are more different" which will result in more different $k$-uples available. I wonder how I will be able to continue using this strategy when $n$ gets over $16$ (we will have to repeat numbers).

Comment: Do you pick the numbers on all tickets simultaneously, or do you get feedback on if you won or not before picking another? If you get no feedback, all strategies will have the same expected value.

Comment: You choose all $n$ tickets having no additional information/feedback given for each ticket you choose. Why will all strategies have the same expected value?

Comment: Intuitively, it is because each number has the same chance of being a winning number, so it doesn't matter which number you choose. Crucially, this is still true after you set the first ticket. Initially, each number has a 6/100 chance of being correct. Say you choose (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) first. Now, each number (including the ones you chose earlier) still has a 6/100 chance of being correct. So, it doesn't matter if you choose overlapping numbers or non-overlapping numbers.

Comment: Unspoken issue whether the lottery ticket purchaser is (*relatively*) **risk-seeking** or **risk averse**.  If risk-averse (ignoring that risk aversion suggests no lottery tickets), you want to maximize the probability of not walking away totally empty handed.  So, you would seek to avoid overlap of the numbers.  If risk-seeking, you want to increase the probability that you suddenly become the wealthiest human on earth.  So, you choose the same exact numbers on all of the cards.  ...see next comment

Comment: My previous comment assumes that (unlike horse racing), you get a fixed prize for hitting (for example) all 6 out of 6, **for** each separate card that hits all 6 out of 6.

Comment: Even for the simple case where $x_i=1$ for $i=2,3,\dots$, there is no algorithm to find the exact optimum. See this paper for a good introduction to the problem: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266448641_Lotto_Designs

Answer (score 1):

The chance that any 1 number is correct is $\frac{6}{100}$. It should be clear that when we pick our first ticket, all options are equivalent, so we can set it to (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6). Then, we can consider whether to choose overlapping numbers, or new numbers for the next ticket. Let us look at the extremes. We could choose the exact same numbers again for the second ticket. In this case, we double the expected value, as whichever payout we would get from the first ticket, it is doubled by the second ticket. Alternatively, we could choose all different numbers. In this case, we also double the expected value, as the chance that some amount of our numbers are correct is doubled by doubling our guesses. I haven't worked it out explicitly, but it should be clear that this holds true for all other choices of how many numbers should overlap.

Intuitively, choosing overlapping numbers increases the reward for winning, and choosing non-overlapping numbers increases the chance of winning, which have the same impact on the expected value.